# How many UARTs can I add to RP2040 using PIO?

Tags: pi-pico

There are a few examples of using the RP2040's PIO capability to add additional UARTs, e.g., the [`uart_tx`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/pio/uart_tx) example.

The RP2040 data sheet describes "two PIO blocks with four state machines each", and the state machines seem to operate independently.

Is it correct then that using the PIOs we can obtain 8 additional UARTs, in addition to the two "real" UARTs?

Comment: May I suggest you create one UART and check the amount of resources used.  That will answer your question.

Comment: There's lots of PIO UART implementations in various languages and frameworks:  https://arduino-pico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/piouart.html   https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/8-uarts-using-asm_pio-pio-dma-micropython-on-the-rpi-pico/   https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=333550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon scan of the API reference, you *could* do 8 additional PIO UARTs *if* you only need them to be simplex, as in transmit-only or receive-only.  In that you likely need bidirectionality on these UARTs, you will consume one state machine for receive and another for transmit, per UART.

Comment: What if you have two receive-only inputs at the same baud rate, could you read them both with the same state machine?

Comment: any examples ho to do it?

Comment: Best to ask a new question, but there are two examples: https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/pio/uart_rx or https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/tree/master/pio/uart_tx